# How to change tab height in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

As you may have already noticed that the open tab height(s) is(are) too bulky.

Comment: Makes more sense to actually move the answer part in the section below.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is the solution.

What you get after doing this.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Step 1: First you need to install a plugin called Material theme.
Step 2: Change the tab height as desired.

step 1:
1) Go to settings:

[image]

2) Click on plugins > browser repositories

[image]

3) Search for 'Material Theme UI'

[image]

as you can see  i have already installed it. After it gets installed you will have to restart intellij.

Step 2: Now,
1) Again Go to settings.
2) Expand Appearance & Behavior > Material, then on the right hand side change the tab height as desired as shown here.

[image]

then click on Apply and boom you can see the change.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer; I also do not like the large tab size the Material UI Theme sets in IntelliJ-based IDEs. Small update for 2022: this is now under Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Material Theme UI > ***Settings*** and then on the right panel, Tab Height is under the "Advanced Settings" section under the "Tabs" tab.

Comment: Tab height is now locked under "premium" on Material Theme UI

Answer (score 13):

In 2023 Intellij Idea:

If you use new UI, go to "Appearance & Behavior" -> "New UI" and then select "Compact mode" from the right side.

That will make tabs and some other menus look more accurate and compact.

Comment: Thanks, any chance to change tabs width to distinct amount of symbols?